# Understanding Vegetation Indices values

Tags: vegetation

I am using VIs such as NDVI, RENDVI, SAVI, SAVI2 etc.

What I cannot understand is what do the values that I read stand for. It is not obvious, and it is logic, because each VI is made of different equation, so represents a different meaning.

How can I "decode" VIs?

Is there a rule to follow?

I found topics like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322416/understanding-why-msavi-ii-values-are-outside-the-theoretical-range but I cannot say it helped.